# Can I dynamically change scss file to use in Vue app?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

Is there a possibility to get `.scss` file from the server and start using it in my `Vue app`? Let's say I want to get `.scss` file with `color variables` and I have 3 different applications on `Vue` for the same company. And to be consistent I want to use **the same colors for all apps**. But they can be changed on the server and then in all 3 apps colors should change.

Comment: If they run on different servers I think you'd have to store the file online somehow, a CDN or something. But even then, SCSS has to compile down to CSS anyway so you'd have to run the build again. Sounds like more work than it's worth to be honest

Comment: I even tried with CDN but it didn't work out. Maybe the problem was in `scoped` style I don't know. As for me, I think that `css` should always be some `static file` but in my current project there is a task which assumes to try to get css file from the server and apply it to the app.

Answer (score 0):

If it is something such simple as colors then you can use CSS variables instead of SCSS.

[To quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) from the docs:

> Custom properties (sometimes referred to as CSS variables or cascading variables) are entities defined by CSS authors that contain specific values to be reused throughout a document. They are set using custom property notation (e.g., `--main-color: black;`) and are accessed using the `var()` function (e.g., `color: var(--main-color);`).